# Jenkins 2 Job: process only changed files from download

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a Jenkins 2 Pipeline job which downloads a file and performs some processings. The job is triggered periodically, so sometimes the downloaded file has not changed.

The question is now: how can I check if the file has changed from the last run to stop and avoid the processing? As an additional difficulty the name of the file changes on every download :-(

Kind regards, Christian

Comment: you mean pipeline job right ??  also when you say the files name changes do you mean version number or the name completely itself changes ??

Comment: The file name of the downloaded file changes (I call a REST service which returns a file). The job which downloads the file is a pipeline job.

Comment: The downloaded file is a text, rar, zip file ?? Also the download location of the file is it fixed and are there any other files present in that location ??

Comment: It is a text file downloaded in a subdirectory of the current build workspace. The location is fixed.

Comment: So you'll have to basically read the contents in the file.... Is there something in the file that distinguish it from the old file ?

Comment: I am thinking of building an MD5 checksum. archiveArtifacts and fingerprinting would do, but in my case it is not a PostBuild action, I would have to call it immediately after the download.

Comment: Yeah that wouldn't be an issue since you are doing it using a pipeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it:

First, compute CRC, save it in an file and archive it. Fingerprinting won't work in my case, because I want to check a zip file which is generated on the fly and has always a different CRC. So I extract the CRC of the files I am interested in and store them in a file `crc.txt`. This might be overkill in most cases.

```groovy
def currentCrc = readFile('crc.txt')
archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'crc.txt', fingerprint: true
```

Then I search the last successful build with a `crc.txt` file and read the content of the file:

```groovy
// find last successful build
def lastSuccessfulBuild = currentBuild.getPreviousBuild()
while (lastSuccessfulBuild && (lastSuccessfulBuild.currentResult != 'SUCCESS')) {
    lastSuccessfulBuild = lastSuccessfulBuild.getPreviousBuild()
}

// and read the 'crc.txt' file of this build
def build = lastSuccessfulBuild?.getRawBuild()
def artifact = build.getArtifacts().find { it.fileName == 'crc.txt' }
def uri = build.artifactManager.root().child(artifact.relativePath).toURI()
def oldCrc = uri.toURL().text
```

And finally I compare the two values (current crc and crc from last successful build:

```groovy
if (oldCrc != currentCrc) {
    println "*** Abort job, because file has not changed."
    return 
}
```